# Android Multiline text-only background

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I want to implement a text view like this in my Android project:

[image]

The text can be multi-line and has a background, but the background must only cover the text and not the remaining empty area.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your highlighting has rounded corners. If you do want the rounded corners, take a look at [Drawing a rounded corner background on text](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/drawing-a-rounded-corner-background-on-text-5a610a95af5), a Medium post by Florina Muntenescu.

That solution leaves some space between the lines while you example fills that space in, but I think that you can modify the code to fill it in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`BackgroundColorSpan`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/BackgroundColorSpan) to set the background color from starting index to an end index of the TextView:

```
val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
val spannable = SpannableString(textView.text.toString())
spannable.setSpan(
    BackgroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#C8ECFD")),
    0,
    spannable.length,
    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
)
textView.text = spannable
```

Comment: Is this flexible to support rounded corners and paddings?

Comment: @Mousa No it's not that easy, you need to customize that using canvas